# nginx Ubuntu nodeJs - Server only handles requests from local network

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I followed all kinds of instructions all day to get my first server up and running.  I tested it on 3 devices and thought I had it... until my friend tried it and discovered "site can't be reached."

In double-checking on my end, I found that if I disconnected my phone from wi-fi, sure enough, I couldn't reach my server.

I realize there could be a million things wrong, but I don't know where to start.  I am not even sure what additional information I should include to help find the issue.  If I had to guess, I'd say I failed to open the firewall on my server port 80.  But I really have no clue.  Ubuntu is new to me.

Comment: It's working.  I had to forward the port on the router.  Thanks.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. Please accept it so this can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include details about your setup? How is the Ubuntu server configured? If it's your own hardware, have you forwarded the ports on your router? Do you have a Dynamic DNS server in place? Is there an internal firewall (ufw?). Is the Node.js server bound to the loopback? Is Nginx in `proxy_pass` mode?

As mentioned by the OP, the ports weren't forwarded.